# I want to export from wikimapia into kml all sugar refinery category points

Tags: kml, wikimapia

I want to select a country in wikimapia and then export all sugar refinery points into a kml file. Also how do I find the category id for sugar refinery?

Comment: Can you give an example of one location? Then express what you have tried, along with your final goal. Your question can be improved.